# Get Byte Position during Upload Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filereader, arraybuffer

I am working on a function that will write data to a remote server in chunks using a 3rd party API. Through some help on Stack Overflow I was able to accomplish this, where it is now working as expected. The problem is that I can only get a single 16kb chunk to write as I will need to advance the `pos` of where the next bytes are written to.

The initial write starts at 0 easily enough. Due to my unfamiliarity with this though, I am unsure if the next `pos` should just be 16 or what. If it helps, the API call `writeFileChunk()` takes 3 parameters, filepath (str), pos (int64), and data (base64 encoded string).

```
    reader.onload = function(evt)
    {
        // Get SERVER_ID from URL
        var server_id = getUrlParameter('id');

        $("#upload_status").text('Uploading File...');
        $("#upload_progress").progressbar('value', 0);

        var chunkSize = 16<<10;
        var buffer = evt.target.result;
        var fileSize = buffer.byteLength;
        var segments = Math.ceil(fileSize / chunkSize); // How many segments do we need to divide into for upload
        var count = 0;

        // start the file upload
        (function upload()
        {
            var segSize = Math.min(chunkSize, fileSize - count * chunkSize);

            if (segSize > 0)
            {
                $("#upload_progress").progressbar('value', (count / segments));

                var chunk = new Uint8Array(buffer, count++ * chunkSize, segSize); // get a chunk
                var chunkEncoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chunk));

                // Send Chunk data to server
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "filemanagerHandler.php",
                    data: { 'action': 'writeFileChunk', 'server_id': server_id, 'filepath': filepath, 'pos': 0, 'chunk': chunkEncoded },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        setTimeout(upload, 100);
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); alert("Message: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $("#upload_status").text('Finished!');
                $("#upload_progress").progressbar('value', 100);

                getDirectoryListing(curDirectory);
            }
        })()
    };
```

Comment: What's that 3rd party API, and does the documentation not mention this? // To assume that it might really just be the byte position seems to be a fair enough guess - so what results did you get when you tried that?

Comment: If this 3rd party api only allows base64 upload then i wouldn't use it...

Answer (score 8):

The current position for the file on client side would be represented by this line, or more specifically the second argument at the pre-incremental step:

```
var chunk = new Uint8Array(buffer, count++ * chunkSize, segSize);
```

though, in this case it advances (`count++`) before you can reuse it so if you need the actual position (below as `pos`) you can extract it by simply rewriting the line into:

```
var pos = count++ * chunkSize;   // here chunkSize = 16kb
var chunk = new Uint8Array(buffer, pos, segSize);
```

Here each position update will increment 16kb as that is the chunk-size. For progress then it is calculated `pos / fileSize * 100`. This of course assuming using the unencoded buffer size.

The only special case is the last chunk, but when there are no more chunks left to read the position should be equal to the file length (`fileSize`) so it should be pretty straight-forward.

When the ajax call return the server should have the same position unless something went wrong (connection, write access change, disk full etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Filereader API to read the chunks and send it to your remote server.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button>Read entire file in chuncks</button>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
  // Post data to your server.
  function postChunk(obj) {
    var url = "https://your.remote.server";
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        var params = "";
        // check that obj has the proper keys and create the url parameters
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(action) && obj.hasOwnProperty(server_id) && obj.hasOwnProperty(filepath) && obj.hasOwnProperty(pos) && obj.hasOwnProperty(chunk)) {
            params += "action="+obj[action]+"&server_id="+obj[server_id]+"&filepath="+obj[filepath]+"&pos="+obj[pos]+"&chunk="+obj[chunk];
          }
        if(params.length>0) {
        xhr.send(params);
        } else {
        alert('Error');
        }       
    });
  }
// add chunk to "obj" object and post it to server
function addChunk(reader,obj,divID) {
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        obj.chunk = evt.target.result;
      console.log(obj);
            document.getElementById(divID).textContent += 
            ['Sending bytes: ', obj.pos*16000, ' - ', ((obj.pos*16000)+(obj.pos+1)*obj.chunk.length),
             '\n'].join('');
      // post data to server
      postChunk(obj).then(function(data) {  
          if(data!=="" && data!==null && typeof data!=="undefined") {
            // chunk was sent successfully
            document.getElementById(divID).textContent += 
            ['Sent bytes: ', obj.pos*16000, ' - ', ((obj.pos*16000)+(obj.pos+1)*obj.chunk.length),'\n'].join('');
          } else {
          alert('Error! Empty response');   
          }
        }, function(status) {
          alert('Resolve Error');
        });
      }
    };
}
 // read and send Chunk
 function readChunk() {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }
    var file = files[0];
    var size = parseInt(file.size);
    var chunkSize = 16000;
    var chunks = Math.ceil(size/chunkSize);
    var start,stop = 0;
    var blob = [];
    for(i=0;i<chunks;i++) {
    start = i*chunkSize;
    stop = (i+1)*chunkSize-1;
    if(i==(chunks-1)) {
    stop = size;
    } 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    blob = file.slice(start, stop);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    var obj = {action: 'writeFileChunk', server_id: 'sid', filepath: 'path', pos: i, chunk: ""};   
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "bytes"+i;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    addChunk(reader,obj,div.id);       
    }  
 }
// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  console.log(' Great success! All the File APIs are supported.');
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      readChunk();
    }
  }, false);
```

You can check this example in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk0hj54w/3/)